# error There was an error in your GraphQL query: Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, netlify

The title above is the error message, and below is the code.
I ran into this while following a tutorial on Gatsby. I wonder if anybody knows what happened and can give me some idea on what happened. I have little idea on what is going on . sorry......

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { parseImageUrl } from '@conradlin/notabase/src/utils'


export default ({ data }) => {
  const { posts: { title, tags, publish_date, html, url, slug, desc, color, cover_image } } = data

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div id = "main">
        <div>{tags && tags.join(', ')}</div> 
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    posts(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      html
      title
      tags
      publish_date{
        startDate(formatString: "YYYY-MMM-DD", fromNow: false)
      }
      url
      desc
      color
      cover_image
    }
  }
```

The tutorial is here for reference
https://conradlin.com/blog/posts/host-gatsbyjs-blog-with-notion-cms-and-netlify-for-free

This should be the query code

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const blogPost = await graphql(`
  query {
      allPosts(filter: {status: {eq: "published"}, content_type: {eq: "article"}}) {
          nodes {
            slug
            url
          }
        }
      }
    `).then(result => {
      if (result.errors) {
        Promise.reject(result.errors);
      }
      
      result.data.allPosts.nodes.forEach(({ slug, url }) => {
        createPage({
            path: `blog/posts/${url}`,
            component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blogPost.js`),
            context: {
                // Data passed to context is available
                // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
                slug: slug,
            },
        });
    });
  });
  const newsPost = await graphql(`
  query {
      allPosts(filter: {status: {eq: "published"}, content_type: {eq: "newsletter"}}) {
          nodes {
            slug
            url
          }
        }
      }
    `).then(result => {
      if (result.errors) {
        Promise.reject(result.errors);
      }
      
      result.data.allPosts.nodes.forEach(({ slug, url }) => {
        createPage({
            path: `subscribe/posts/${url}`,
            component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blogPost.js`),
            context: {
                // Data passed to context is available
                // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
                slug: slug,
            },
        });
    });
  });

  return Promise.all([blogPost, newsPost]);
};
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code that actually fires the query, because thats what is throwing your error

Answer (score 0):

If you look at:

```
  result.data.allPosts.nodes.forEach(({ slug, url }) => {
    createPage({
        path: `subscribe/posts/${url}`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blogPost.js`),
        context: {
            // Data passed to context is available
            // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
            slug: slug,
        },
    });
```

This snippet refers to the `gatsby-node.js`, where you create pages dynamically based on a GraphQL query for `allPosts`. In this case, you are creating each post that will have the following URL:

```
path: `subscribe/posts/${url}`,
```

However, to filter the data for each particular post, you need to pass to the template (set with `component: path.resolve('./src/templates/blogPost.js')`) you need to pass an identifier field, typically the `id`, the `slug` or some other unique value. That flow of data is done due to the context, where you tell what parameter is passed to the component template, the slug in this case:

```
context: {
    // Data passed to context is available
    // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
    slug: slug,
},
```

Thereby, in you template you can do:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    posts(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      html
      title
      tags
      publish_date{
        startDate(formatString: "YYYY-MMM-DD", fromNow: false)
      }
      url
      desc
      color
      cover_image
    }
  }
```

Notice the `($slug: String!)` the exclamation mark (`!`) means that the field is non-nullable for the GraphQL query, or in other words, that is required. Your code is breaking because somewhere in your GraphQL query (in your `gatsby-node.js`) you are passing an empty/`null` value to that template and the query breaks.

Debug what's happening in that query or remove the non-nullable parameter by:

```
query($slug: String)
```

However, that will bypass the code-breaking but the issue will persist since you are providing an empty value.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer and clarifying things. Can you please suggest which part of the code in gatsby-node.js is null or empty? I have updated the code up above. I tried removing the non-nullable parameter and the error remains

Comment: Your `slug` seems to be null in your `forEach` loop. Try adding a debugger/`console.log` there to know what's happening there. Try passing the `url` parameter instead of the slug, it should be unique so it will work